# QGIS version 3.32.1, after packaging independent application loading raster data could not correctly read the coordinate system

Tags: pyqgis

QGIS version 3.32.1, secondary development in PyCharm, after packaging independent application loading raster data could not correctly read the coordinate system。
autorsrs.py：

```
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('./qgis', True)       
    qgs = QgsApplication([], True)    
    qgs.initQgis()
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    exit_code = qgs.exec_()
    # quit
    qgs.exitQgis()
    sys.exit()
```

While running in PyCharm, after loaded r_layer ,run "self.r_layer.crs()" code ,the result is "<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:4524>",

but after packaging, the result is

```
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: ENGCRS["CGCS2000 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 36",EDATUM["Unknown engineering datum"],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]>"`
```

This is packaging file：

```
name build.bat
"D:\QGIS 3.32.1\bin\python-qgis.bat" -m PyInstaller -w ^
--icon=icon\rsrs.ico ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\share\proj;qgis\proj" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qgis\resources;qgis\resources" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\gdal\share\gdal;qgis\gdal" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qgis\plugins;qgis\plugins" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\*.pyd;PyQt5" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qt5\plugins\styles;PyQt5\Qt\plugins\styles" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qt5\plugins\iconengines;PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qt5\plugins\imageformats;PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qt5\plugins\platforms;PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms" ^
--add-data="D:\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qt5\plugins\platformthemes;PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platformthemes" ^
autorsrs\AutoRSRS.py
```